# Is it possible to disable a default keyboard shortcut for a special character, without the use of third-party software?

Tags: macos, shortcut, text, customization

I have set <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to execute the command "Paste and Match Style", system-wide. I assigned this custom shortcut at the following location:

*System Preferences* → *Keyboard* → *App Shortcuts* → *All Applications*

However, instead of the desired effect of pasting and matching style, pressing <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> on my keyboard usually types the character `µ` instead. Only every so often does my shortcut randomly function correctly.

How can I disable the assignment of this special character to my shortcut, so that the shortcut is dedicated to my user-defined command? I never have the need to type this Mu character, so I have no problem with ridding it from my keyboard entirely.

I understand that one can use a re-mapping program (such as Karabiner.app) as a workaround to accomplish this. But, does Apple offer a *built-in* way to remove special character shortcuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, since I know you use **[FastScripts](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/)**, here's a suggestion.

Undo the changes you made in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Application Shortcuts** > **All Applications**, by first changing **⌥M** back to **⌥⇧⌘V**, then delete the **Paste and Match Style** *command* you added. Note that you could probably just delete it without first reseting it to its default key sequence, however I do it this way to insure it gets reset properly.

With things back to normal, create an **AppleScript .scpt** using the *code* below, saving it as **Paste and Match Style.scpt** in the **Users Script Folder** (~/Library/Scripts).

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 9 using {option down, shift down, command down}
```

Note that you can also use `keystroke "v"` in place of `key code 9`, I just prefer to use `key code` over `keystroke` most of the time.

In **FastScripts** > **Preferences...** > **Script Shortcuts**, assign **⌥M** to: **Paste and Match Style**

Now you will not get the **µ** character when pressing **⌥M** when **FastScripts** is running.

Answer (score 1):

Apple always uses Option/alt for special characters. Just use Control or Command for the functions you want instead.

Comment: The **⌘** key is also already bound to almost the entire alphabet and other characters like **+**, **-**, **[**, **]**, **0** _thru_ **9**, etc. throughout the combined installed apps, so **⌘** is not ideal for two key combo to circumvent a default like **⌥M**, as **⌘M** is set to **Minimize**. My suggested workaround is IMO a good option in this case since I know that rubik's sphere uses FastScript.

Comment: Ctrl is bound to much less though. The answer is IMHO not correct anyway because it does not actually answer the question but simply propose a workaround. It should have been a comment at most.

Comment: I think that using the Control key is a fine idea. My gripe is that Apple surely is aware that the majority of Mac users never have the need to type any special characters. Yet, they continue to dedicate a number of shortcuts to these esoteric symbols. I guess that Apple's rebuttal would be... _"How many people need more keyboard shortcuts than the dozens of shortcuts that the ctrl key provides?"_

Comment: @rubik'ssphere Apple gets 2/3 of its sales from outside the US in fact spends a lot of effort to localize MacOS and iOS and provide easy modes of input for languages other than English.